# An endomorphism of a field is the identity on a subfield. Is it an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a subfield of a field $L$, both infinite. Let $\phi$ be an endomorphism on $L$ such that $\phi|_{K} = id|_{K}$

Is it true that $\phi$ is an automorphism?

I believe, it is so if $L$ is a finite extension of $K$.
A counter example for finite $K$ and infinite $L$ would be the Frobenius's endomorphism on $\mathbb{Z}_2(t)$, which is identity on $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but not surjective.

Comment: A simpler, if less natural, counterexample when finiteness isn't assumed is gotten from $L=\mathbb{Q}(\{t_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\})$, $K=\mathbb{Q}$, and $\phi$ generated by sending $t_i$ to $t_{i+1}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Thank you! That is what I was looking for, a counterexample for an infinite field K.

Comment: To summarize the efforts of NoahSchweber, egreg and lhf:

Every endomorphism on a field $L$, which is an automorphism (not necessarily the identity) on a subfield $K$, is an automorphism on $L$ if an only if $L$ is a finite extension of $K$. We can prove this by counting dimensions of finite extensions. Counterexamples for infinite extensions: for a finite $K$ is $K=\mathbb{Z}_2, L=\mathbb{Z}_2(t)$, $\phi(x)=x^2$; for an infinite $K$ is $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\{t_i:i\in \mathbb{N}\})$, $\phi(t_i)=t_{i+1}$.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is right. Any endomorphism of a field $L$ induces the identity on the prime subfield, but need not be an automorphism if $L$ is infinite and your example is fine.

Indeed, if $L$ is a finite extension of $K$, then counting dimensions will show that an endomorphism inducing an automorphism on $K$ is necessarily surjective, because $[L:K]=[L:\phi(L)][\phi(L):\phi(K)]$ and $[\phi(L):\phi(K)]=[L:K]$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant of the argument given by @egreg.

A ring homomorphism between fields that preserves the multiplicative identity is necessarily injective because there are no nontrivial ideals in a field.

Therefore, $\phi$ is an injective $K$-linear transformation and so is surjective when $L$ is a finite extension of $K$.

Comment: Yes, this works if $\phi$ induces the identity on $K$. My argument is more general.